# How to find the line causing this stack overflow error

Tags: java, stack-overflow

The purpose of this program (college assignment) is to take an input from the user (char data type) and see how many this char exists in an char array using recursion method. A helper method is also necessary.

I made my helper method to be the one to determine whether the program should call another method or not (it will keep continuing calling if the high is greater than one; high is the pointer counting from the highest location going down to zero--the first array member).

I got the StackOverFlowError at line 48 and 63. I tried going it manually to make sure the program would reach an end, but no luck. I cannot figure out where the error is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**Scanner object*/
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        /**Variables*/
        char findThisChar;
        char[] thisArray = {'m', 'y', 'y'};
        int counter;

        /**Prompt the user to enter the char that will be counted*/
        System.out.print("Please enter the character to be found: ");
        findThisChar = userInput.next().charAt(0);

        counter = getCharCountHelper(thisArray, findThisChar, thisArray.length - 1);

        System.out.print("There are " + counter + " " + findThisChar + " in the array.");

    }

    private static int getCharCountHelper(char[] thisArray, char findThisChar, int high) {

        int count = 0;
        if(high <= 0){
            if(high == findThisChar){
                count++;
                return count;
            }
            else {
                return count;
            }
        }
        else {
            **count += getCharCount(thisArray, findThisChar, high);**
        }
        return count;

    }

    private static int getCharCount(char[] thisArray, char findThisChar, int high) {

        int count = 0;

        if(thisArray[high] == findThisChar){
            count++;
            count += getCharCountHelper(thisArray, findThisChar, high--);
        }
        else{
            **count += getCharCountHelper(thisArray, findThisChar, high--);**
        }
        return count;

    }

}
```

How can I find where the looping problem is?

Comment: Since we can't see line numbers, it would be nice of you to point out the lines in your listing. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I completely forget about that. I have marked the two lines with ** in the beginning and the end of the lines.

Comment: A couple problems I can see. I thing that the high-- should be --high. Also, you compare high time findThisChar once directly and once as an array index.

Comment: Thank you. I will try doing --high. About the second part of your suggestion, the reason why I compare the high value directly is to see the coordinate. If the high value is zero, meaning the pointer position is already at the very front (e.g. theArray[0]), then I wouldn't want to let the program to call another method. Or is this way of thinking flawed? EDIT: Yes. The problem seems to be the --high instead of high--. I just realized that high-- technically means do it first before reducing the high which would be an infinite loop.

Comment: There is a comparison of high to finfThusChar with a direct ==

Comment: I just saw what you meant. Thank you very much to point that out. I didn't realize that one as well.

Comment: If it still isn't working, use print statements or a debugger to make sure that high is decreasing. Then, asd more stack space to java. Google "java more stack spac3"